# Which could be the best solution for Wifi Card for a project

Tags: arduino, pic, wifi

I'm new so sorry if my title isn't the best. I wanted to know (as I google it and didn't find a satisfactory answer) where can I find a Wifi Card connection for a project.

I have a little device I have been designing, and now I want it to communicate via wifi, since I did it with PIC and Arduino, I already find a MicroElectronika and Arduino WIDI Shield, but both are too expensive for my project so I wanted to know if someone had used another option for it, I'm just asking for the link and if it has documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you also have considered the WiFly Shield https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954 for USD 70.

Yes, that is expensive compared to, say, an RF Link Transmitter https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534 for USD 4.

What you get with the first module is all the WiFi on-air protocols, and TCP/IP.  Awesome complexity and high power draw.

With the second module you don't get WiFi protocols, you have to use your own, and you have to buy a receiver module as well.  But the cost is great.  With a much lower power draw.

You might like to consider it as an alternative; wireless, but not WiFi.

*(Disclaimer: a research institution owned by my government owns some of the patents in the WiFi portfolio, so I'm a beneficiary at a distance of the additional cost of the first module.)*

Comment: The roving networks module has worked well for me in places. Note you'll need to jump through some hoops to be able to upload code to the Arduino through a wifi module.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at TIs [CC3000](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3000). It is rather new, and one of the cheapest WiFi solutions available. E.g. the [Adafruit breakout](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1469) is only $35 right now.

If this is still to expensive, you can look into using a [WLAN router as shield](http://www.martinmelchior.be/2013/07/use-tp-link-tl-wr703n-to-send-arduino.html).

Comment: Exactly. Short of the cc3000 or essentially an embedded pc like a router, you won't find anything cheap. Outside of the US, the wifi pocket router would be the best choice. for under 50 bucks.